# Fetching expiry of the session from URL

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection, session-timeout

I'm trying to fetch information from a `URL`, i.e. to know *When the session time has expired from URL?* For example, if you trying to connect to a `URL` and downloading a file with IDM from Mediafire, then you pause it. After 4 hours since your first connection to the Mediafire's `URL`, you're trying to re-connect and resume your download. Unfortunately, you get a message saying:

> 403: Forbidden. You don't have permission to access file.zip on this server.

or this message:

> Probably this site uses temporary links that cannot be requested twice or expire after some time when session is completed.

It means that Mediafire gives us max time to re-connect. So you have to resume your download in that interval.

I have tried:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
urlConnection.connect();
String exp = urlConnection.getHeaderField("Expires");
System.out.println("Expire date: " + exp);
```

Output:

```
Expire date: null // while responseCode is 200 OK
```

Sometimes, with different `URL`, I got `Tue, 03 Nov 2015 03:41:09 PST`.

*So, how do I know when the session time has expired certainly?*

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to RFC there is not always a expires header field.

[Section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3)

> An origin server without a clock MUST NOT generate an Expires field
> unless its value represents a fixed time in the past (always expired)
> or its value has been associated with the resource by a system or
> user with a reliable clock.

[Furthermore it defines the Freshness in 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2)

> If an origin server wishes to force a cache to validate every
> request, it can assign an explicit expiration time in the past to
> indicate that the response is already stale.  Compliant caches will
> normally validate a stale cached response before reusing it for
> subsequent requests (see Section 4.2.4).

> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
> caches are also allowed to use a heuristic to determine an expiration
> time under certain circumstances (see Section 4.2.2).

[So in order to get a somewhat reliable headerfield you can calculate it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2.2)

> Since origin servers do not always provide explicit expiration times,
> a cache MAY assign a heuristic expiration time when an explicit time
> is not specified, employing algorithms that use other header field
> values (such as the Last-Modified time) to estimate a plausible
> expiration time.  This specification does not provide specific
> algorithms, but does impose worst-case constraints on their results.